# Segmentation fault help for linked list newbie in C

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, nodes

I am trying to make a priority queue for "printing jobs" that a user inputs.  A string is entered followed by a space and then a number (0-9) as the priority of the job.  Once "NONE" is entered, the program stops taking input and I will eventually write the code to print out the jobs in order of their priority.  The code isn't close to being finished but is already causing a segmentation fault.  I have stared at the code for about two hours and don't see anything wrong.  I also could not find any questions that I could figure out the problem from.  I assume I am just doing something stupid and cannot see it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node
{
    int priority;
    char *dataString;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *first = NULL;

int main(void)
{

    char temporaryPriority;
    int i = 0;

    while(i != 1)
    {
        struct node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        if (newNode == NULL)
        {
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        scanf("%s", (newNode -> dataString));

        if ((strcmp((newNode -> dataString), "NONE") != 0) && (strcmp((newNode -> dataString), "none") != 0))

        {
            scanf(" %c", &temporaryPriority);

            (newNode -> priority) = temporaryPriority;

            (newNode -> next) = first;
            first = newNode;
        }
        else 
        {
            i = 1;
            free(newNode);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Staring at code is generally unproductive.  It looks the same after two hours as it did when you started.  Using a debugger, however, is often very useful, as is a memory-analysis tool such as valgrind.  Just adding printf() statements to follow the progress of the code would have revealed the problem area well befor 2 hours were up.  Please stop writing programs until you have some rudimentary debugging skills and the will to use them yourself.

Comment: Aparrently, you have been on a CS course for three months.  Please tell your prof/TA to instruct their students on troubleshooting and debugging NOW, before it issues any more pointless, timewasting homework.

Comment: @MartinJames I currently do not have access to a debugger as I am required to program on a server that only has GCC installed.  I was using printf statements and commenting out sections of the code as an attempt to figure out the problem.  What you are looking at above is actually a rewritten version that I thought would clear out any mistakes that I had not seen.   I have not learned anything about debugging yet and was thinking of starting with gdb, but I will also look into valgrind.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Please modify `char *dataString;` to `char dataString[50];`, the `50` just a fake number, you can define it  according your occation.

The reason is that you do `scanf("%s", (newNode -> dataString));`, but you don't alloc memory for `newNode -> dataString`.

**Second way:**
allocate memory for the node:

```
struct node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
newNode->dataString  = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
```

free the memory for the node:

```
free(newNode->dataString);
free(newNode);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out to me.  Is there a way to dynamically allocate memory for dataString[] while it is in a node?

Comment: @Glace yes, but you already know this because you have already mallocated the node itself and, so, I cannot understand why you would ask how to allocate memory for dataString[]?

Comment: ..especially as you have been on your CS course for at least 3 months.